# Passing Collection from Blade to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am working on an application and need to pass data from Blade back to the controller

I am passing the data to the blade like this

```
$reports = $query->paginate();
return view('admin.report', compact('reports'));
```

this works fine, however I want to have a button to pass $reports collection to this function

```
public function exportToCSV(Document $reports)
```

this is going to create a CSV file that will be downloaded including every entry from $reports

I have doing a lot of googling on this and have even have someone help me try to figure it out to no avail.

Comment: I think you can create a button link to a route that calls de controller method you want.

Comment: that's what i tried at first but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be with a form. You can have a hidden input, with the collection as the value. You would define a route for the form to POST to, and call your function from the route in `web.php`.

```
    <form action="/route/to/wherever/" method="POST">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden"
     name="key"
     value="{{ $collection }}"
      >
    </form>
```

Be sure to add a submit button. In your method you would receive the collection like:

```
public function myFunction(Request $request){
$data = $request->key;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that ended up doing it, had to make a few other changes to my controller code but it works much better than another method i was trying.

Comment: I tried this exact thing thinking it would work. I get this error" htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: @Lyrical.me You can try wrapping the variable in `json_encode($variable)`